Re-Organize Task IDs in MS Project
In MS Project Professional (Online Desktop Client), I made several tasks that are all occurring simultaneously, with nested tasks for each one. To prioritize and organize my task list in order of importance, I dragged the tasks around. Now, my task ID list is all jumbled up and it won't save all of sub-task rearrangements that I do.
Is there any way that I can drag all my tasks in the order that I want and then set the task IDs to auto update in numerical order?
Thanks


tyster02, Go to, View > Data group > Sort. By default the sort feature will show a sort by ID. Check the option to "permanently renumber tasks".
